# Riemann curvature tensor identity proof

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, covariance, general-relativity

Let $R_{abcd}$ be the Riemann curvature tensor defined by a torsion free and metric compatible covariant derivative.

Ultimately I am trying to prove that $R_{abcd} = -  R_{abdc}$

The prove in my textbook is as follows: (However I really am unsure as to what is happening here)

*We know that $\nabla g_{bc} = 0$ , since we have been told that is metric compatible.
If we compute $\nabla_a\nabla_bg_{cd} - \nabla_b\nabla_ag_{cd} $ we have the following:
$$0 = \nabla_a\nabla_bg_{cd} - \nabla_b\nabla_ag_{cd} = R_{abc}^{\space \space \space \space \space  i}g_{id}  + R_{abd} ^{\space \space \space \space \space  i}g_{ci} =  R_{abcd} +R_{abdc}  $$*

The part I am struggling to understand is where the term $ R_{abc}^{\space \space \space \space \space  i}g_{id}  + R_{abd} ^{\space \space \space \space \space  i}g_{ci}$ came from.

I am aware that $\nabla_a\nabla_dV_b - \nabla_d\nabla_aV_b = R_{adb}^{\space \space \space \space \space  i} V_i$ however I am still unsure as to where the part noted above comes from exactly.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very well versed, but I think the answer to your specific question follows from the metrinilic property of the metric as well the fact that the covariant derivative satisfies *Leibniz's law*; that is, it should be the case that
\begin{align*}
0 &= (\nabla_a\nabla_b- \nabla_b\nabla_a)g_{cd}\\
&= (\nabla_a\nabla_b- \nabla_b\nabla_a)(\textbf{e}_c\cdot \textbf{e}_d)\\
&= ((\nabla_a\nabla_b- \nabla_b\nabla_a)\textbf{e}_c)\cdot\textbf{e}_d + \textbf{e}_c\cdot((\nabla_a\nabla_b- \nabla_b\nabla_a)\textbf{e}_d)\\
&= (R_{abc}^{\space\space\space\space\space\space i}\textbf{e}_{i})\cdot\textbf{e}_d + \textbf{e}_c\cdot(R_{abd}^{\space\space\space\space\space\space i}\textbf{e}_{i})\\
&= R_{abc}^{\space\space\space\space\space\space i}g_{id} + R_{abd}^{\space\space\space\space\space\space i}g_{ci}\\
&= R_{abcd}+R_{abdc}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Huh? What is $g_c$?

Comment: $g_c$ is the covariant basis of the tangent space.

Comment: You mean contravariant? $g$ is the metric tensor, so you need a different letter.

Comment: Sorry, yes the contravariant basis. Also I was not aware that a different letter is required, the text I refer to uses $\textbf{Z}_i$ as the contravariant basis and $Z_{ij}$ as the metric. I can change $g_c$ to $e_c$ in my answer if this is the typical notation?